# При выполнении длительного запроса к БД из одного потока, блокируется параллельный запрос к БД из другого потока

Tags: python, sql-server, многопоточность, pyqt5

**`СУБД - MS SQL SERVER`**

Возникла ситуация, когда я логинюсь к БД, то длительный запрос, снова тормозит первый поток. 
Не могу понять по какой причине, вероятно ему не нравится, что я некорректно добавил подключение к серверу.

Примерно вот так получилось, только здесь не добавил запросы в потоки:

```
import threading
import time
from ui import *
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
import pyodbc
from redminelib import Redmine
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from io import BytesIO
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import webbrowser


class Connect:
    def __init__(self):
        super(Connect, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.server = None
        self.password = None
        self.username = None

    def server_conn(self):
        self.server = self.ui.connwin.text()
        if self.ui.connwin.text() == '':
            self.ui.connwin.setPlaceholderText('Empty')
            return
        self.username = self.ui.ent_login.text()
        if self.ui.ent_login.text() == '':
            self.ui.ent_login.setPlaceholderText('Empty')
            return
        self.password = self.ui.pass_word.text()
        if self.ui.pass_word.text() == '':
            self.ui.pass_word.setPlaceholderText('Empty')
            return
        try:
            """Создается подключение к серверу"""
            self.conn = conn = pyodbc.connect(
                'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + self.server + ';DATABASE=' + self.database + ';UID='
                + self.username + ';PWD=' + self.password, autocommit=True)  # запускает соединение с SQL-сервером
            self.cursor = cursor = conn.cursor()  # создается cursor для соединения
            print('connect succcesfull')
            self.ui.onlineligth.setStyleSheet('background-color: green;  '
                                              'border-radius:5px;'
                                              'font-size: 16px;')
            self.ui.statusonline.setText('Online')
            # If connection is not successful
        except Exception:
            print("Can't connect to database")
            self.ui.statusonline.setText('Offline')
            self.ui.onlineligth.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;'
                                              'border-radius:5px;'
                                              'font-size: 16px;')
            return


class MyThread(QtCore.QObject, Connect):
    mysignal1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, object)  # !!!

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self._stopped = True
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()

    def run(self):
        self._stopped = False
        print('start')
        self.change_x()

    def change_x(self):
        while not self._stopped:
            print('My Thread работает')
            application.cursor.execute("""  select TOP 1 
             case when j.name like '%index%' then j.name  
             when j.name like '%update%' then j.name    
             when j.name like '%rchive%' then j.name
             when j.name like '%HS_check%' then j.name else 'No heavy jobs'
             end jobname
          from sys.dm_exec_requests r
            inner join sys.dm_exec_sessions s
              on r.session_id = s.session_id
            cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text ( sql_handle ) t
            inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
              on s.program_name like '%' + master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr( j.job_id ) + '%'   """)
            records = application.cursor.fetchall()

            self.mysignal1.emit('heavy_job', records)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000*1)

            application.cursor.execute("""  SELECT
    CAST((
            MAX(CASE WHEN counter_name = 'CPU usage %' THEN t.cntr_value * 1. END) /
            MAX(CASE WHEN counter_name = 'CPU usage % base' THEN t.cntr_value END)
        ) * 100 as numeric(15,0))  AS cpu_sql
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(2) cntr_value, counter_name
    FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
    WHERE counter_name IN ('CPU usage %', 'CPU usage % base')
        AND instance_name = 'default'
) t  """)
            records = application.cursor.fetchall()

            records = 'тработал запрос для cpu_sql()'
            self.mysignal1.emit('cpu_sql', records)

    def stop(self):
        self._stopped = True  # Видимо данный метод является остановкой для выполнения потока


class MyThread4(QtCore.QObject, Connect):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)  # !!!

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self._stopped = True
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()

    def run(self):
        print('start Mythread2')
        count = 0
        self._stopped = False
        # +        ...   тут ваш длительный запрос   !!!

        application.cursor.execute("""SELECT top 100  
        CASE    WHEN indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent>30 THEN ' REBUILD ' 
        WHEN indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent>=5 THEN 'REORGANIZE'
        end [Fix],
        ind.type_desc as Index_Type,
        OBJECT_NAME(ind.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
        ind.name AS IndexName, 
        str(indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent) as fragmentation,
        'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(ind.name)  + ' ON ' +QUOTENAME(object_name(ind.object_id)) + 
        CASE    WHEN indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent>30 THEN ' REBUILD ' 
                WHEN indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent>=5 THEN 'REORGANIZE'
                ELSE NULL END as [SQLQuery] 
        -- if <5 not required, so no query needed
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) indexstats 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes ind ON ind.object_id = indexstats.object_id 
    AND ind.index_id = indexstats.index_id 
WHERE 
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent   >15 and 
ind.Name is not null 
ORDER BY TableName asc""")
        records = application.cursor.fetchall()
        self.mysignal.emit(records)

    def stop(self):
        self._stopped = True


#######################################################################
    
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Connect):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.tran_text = None
        self.tran = None
        self.task_id = None

        self.conn = None
        self.cursor = None
        self.database = None
        self.ui.connwin.setPlaceholderText('Введите адрес сервера')
        self.ui.ent_login.setPlaceholderText('Введите логин')
        self.ui.pass_word.setPlaceholderText('Введите пароль')
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.ui.butt_conn.clicked.connect(self.server_conn)


        self.ui.startcheckindex.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

        self.ui.start_check.clicked.connect(self.butt_connButton)



        self.thread1 = QtCore.QThread(self)  # +++
        self.worker1 = MyThread()
        self.worker1.moveToThread(self.thread1)
        self.worker1.mysignal1.connect(self.worker1_mysignal1)  # !!!

        #        self.butt_conn.clicked.connect(self.worker1.change_x)
        #        self.thread1.start()
        self.thread1.started.connect(self.worker1.run)  # !!!

        self.thread = QtCore.QThread(self)  # +++
        self.worker = MyThread4()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.mysignal.connect(self.index_frag_inf)  # !!!

        #        self.startcheckindex.clicked.connect(self.worker.second_work)
        #        self.thread.start()

        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)  # !!!


        self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ('Fix',
             'Index Type',
             'TableName',
             'IndexName',
             'fragmentation %',
             'SQLQuery'
             )
        )
        self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 100)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 200)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 300)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(4, 80)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(5, 300)


        self.ui.Monitoractivity.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.dashboard))
        self.ui.indexfragment.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.indexfrag))


    def handleButton(self):
        if self.thread.isRunning():
            self.worker.stop()
        else:
            self.thread.start()

    def butt_connButton(self):
        if self.thread1.isRunning():
            self.worker1.stop()
            self.thread1.quit()
        else:
            self.thread1.start()

    def worker1_mysignal1(self, text, records):  # <----
        if text == 'heavy_job':
            #            self.ui.heavyjob.setText(str(records))
            self.ui.heavyjob.setText(str(records))
        elif text == 'cpu_sql':
            #            self.ui.cpupercent.setText(str(records))
            self.ui.cpupercent.setText(str(records))



    def index_frag_inf(self, records):  # <----
        self.thread.quit()

        self.ui.tableWidget.clearContents()

        #        self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(100)    void QTableWidget::insertRow(int row)
        #        tablerow = 0
        self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(100)

        tablerow = 0
        for index, record in enumerate(records):

            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(index, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(record[0]))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(index, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(record[1]))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(index, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(record[2]))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(index, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(record[3]))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(index, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(record[4]))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(index, 5, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(record[5]))
            tablerow += 1




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = mywindow()
    application.show()
    application.setWindowTitle('Console')
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что ваш драйвер и БД не поддерживает работу через одно подключение нескольких потоков. (В принципе это совершенно обычная практика, что такой поддержки нет). Так что вам скорее всего надо делать в каждом потоке отдельное подключение или воспользоваться пулом подключений, если ваш драйвер это поддерживает

Comment: что за СУБД????

Comment: СУБД MS SQL SERVER

Comment: Да я смотрю у вас там какая-то реорганизация индексов и прочие такие вещи, которые конечно будут тормозить обращение к таблицам. А вообще нужно смотреть детальнее - сколько данных, какие запросы, индексы и т.д.